# Translation for the spanish term "clave de sol mayor"

Tags: translation

I'm looking for a translation of "clave de sol mayor"

My attempts: G MAJOR SCALE and MAJOR SCALE BASED ON G

Comment: No, that's the *key of G major*, but we don’t know Spanish here.

Comment: Notice that it's _clave_, not _llave_; the musical sense of 'key' was re-borrowed from Classical Latin and exists alongside the native Spanish _llave_ 'key', which derives from Vulgar Latin. As for the musical scale, English does not use the _do, re, mi, ..._ of Spanish, but rather alphabetic letters. An English-speaking musician has to think hard to remember what key _Sol_ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia's entry for [Sol mayor](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sol_mayor) links to the English entry for [G major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G_major):

> G major (or the key of G) is a major scale based on G

So it seems that both *G major* or *key of G* seem to be good translations, as they both refer to a *major scale* as indicates by the Spanish *clave mayor*.

Answer (score 0):

On Google translate it shows ***treble clef***